# strftime() format dates not working in Custom Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: 18.04, bash, shortcut-keys, ffmpeg

We were using a Custom Shortcut under the Keyboard settings in Ubuntu 16.04 that allowed us to automatically initiate an ffmpeg screen recording with Super-Z. The command we were using was:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default ~/Videos/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`_screenrecording.mkv; exec bash'
```

Now that we upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 the command is returning blank values for the date variables. Instead of returning a file with the name `2019-05-20_17-41-56_screenrecording.mkv`, for example, it returns a file with the name `--_--_screenrecording.mkv`.

We tested the command straight from the terminal and it works fine.

Any ideas why the Custom Shortcut wouldn't have access to the date variables? Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if they are being interpreted as freedesktop field codes? what happens if you double the `%` signs i.e. `+%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H-%%M-%%S` ?

Comment: @steeldriver please make that an answer